# Beamer themes and bidi problems

Tags: beamer, hebrew, bidi

I'm trying to write a Hebrew beamer presentation. I found some very nice template that actually worked from the box (which you can find [in this very link](http://tx.technion.ac.il/%7Eronen/latex/beamer_hebrew.html), [source](http://tx.technion.ac.il/%7Eronen/latex/beamer-hebrew.tex) and [author's compiled output](http://tx.technion.ac.il/%7Eronen/latex/beamer-hebrew.pdf)) but there are two problems, where my compiled output disagrees with the above:

1. The first is that the list is flushed to the left (even if it aligned to the right), and this doesn't change even if I enclose it in a `flushright` environment.
2. The theorem (second frame) shows up with the title "Theorem" or its Hebrew counterpart defined there. Regardless to any modification and removal of words.

   However, if I disable the theme (`Warsaw`, and other similar to it) then it works out just peachy (It also works with `Hannover`-like themes). But there is no box to contain the theorem as usual.

Is there an easy way to overcome this (except not preparing Hebrew presentations with Beamer)?

If it's any relevance, I'm using Arch Linux and texlive; but the problem persists on my Windows 8.1 tablet with MiKTeX (latest).

---

I managed to correct the second issue by using the `Rochester` theme. But I'd like to understand how this can be solved for other themes like the `Warsaw` theme.

The first issue is somewhat more adamant.

Answer (score 3):

LuaLaTeX+Babel+Beamer+Metropolis work quite well for Hebrew presenations: [presentation](https://digitalwords.net/media/beamer-hebrew/beamer-hebrew.pdf), [source](https://gitlab.com/rwmpelstilzchen/beamer-hebrew/blob/master/beamer-hebrew.tex). 
I haven’t tested it for math, though.

Good luck :-)

Here is a local copy of the source linked above:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex

%%%%%%%%%%
% BEAMER %
%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\PassOptionsToPackage{luatex}{hyperref}

\documentclass[luatex]{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}

% Fix the title separator
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title separator}{
    \bgroup
    \bodydir TLT
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[fg] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth, \metropolis@titleseparator@linewidth);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \egroup
    \par%
}
\makeatother

% Fix the progress bar and make it progress from right to left
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{progress bar in section page}{
    \setlength{\metropolis@progressonsectionpage}{%
        \textwidth * \ratio{\insertframenumber pt}{\inserttotalframenumber pt}%
    }%
    \bgroup
    \bodydir TLT
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[bg] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth, \metropolis@progressonsectionpage@linewidth);
        \fill[fg] (\textwidth,0) rectangle (\textwidth-\metropolis@progressonsectionpage, \metropolis@progressonsectionpage@linewidth);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \egroup
}
\makeatother

% A more logical title page, juxtaposing `institute` to `author`. This modification is not necessary for Hebrew support.
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
  \begin{minipage}[b][\paperheight]{\textwidth}
    \ifx\inserttitlegraphic\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{title graphic}\fi
    \vfill%
    \ifx\inserttitle\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{title}\fi
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{subtitle}\fi
    \usebeamertemplate*{title separator}
    \ifx\beamer@shortauthor\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{author}\fi
    \ifx\insertinstitute\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{institute}\fi
    \ifx\insertdate\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{date}\fi
    \vfill
    \vspace*{1mm}
  \end{minipage}
}
\setbeamertemplate{author}{\vspace*{2em}\insertauthor\par\vspace*{0.25em}}
\setbeamertemplate{institute}{\insertinstitute\par}
\setbeamertemplate{date}{\vspace*{3mm}\insertdate\par}
\makeatother




%%%%%%%%%
% Babel %
%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=he,main]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import=en-GB]{english}
\babelprovide[import=cy]{welsh}

% For some reason Babel’s `\babelfont` doesn’t work
\setsansfont[Script=Hebrew]{Open Sans Hebrew}
\setmonofont{Fira Mono}
\renewcommand{\H}[1]{\foreignlanguage{hebrew}{\fontspec[Script=Hebrew]{Open Sans Hebrew}#1}}
\newcommand{\nikud}[1]{$\mbox{\H{#1}}$}
\newcommand{\E}[1]{\foreignlanguage{english}{\fontspec{Open Sans}#1}}
\newcommand{\C}[1]{\foreignlanguage{welsh}{\fontspec{Open Sans}#1}}
\newcommand{\LR}[1]{{‏\textdir TLT #1}}



%%%%%%%%
% MISC %
%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{metalogo, fancyvrb}

\newcommand{\smallurl}[1]{{\footnotesize\url{#1}}}



%%%%%%%%%%%%
% DOCUMENT %
%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\title{מצגות \E{Beamer} בעברית הן בגדר האפשר}
\subtitle{החלום שכולנו חיכינו לו מתגשם סוף כל סוף}
\author{יודה רונן\quad\foreignlanguage{english}{\smallurl{<https://me.digitalwords.net/>}}}
\institute{האגודה הבינלאומית ל\TeX נולוגיה עברית}
\date{אוגוסט 2018}
\frame{\titlepage}


\begin{frame}{שלום עולם!}
    מה יש לנו כאן?

    \begin{itemize}
        \item פתרון מודרני שלם (אך לא מושלם) ליצירת מצגות עבריות ב־\E{Beamer}.
        \item משתמש במחלקות וחבילות הרגילות, ולא דורש תחזוק של פוֹרְקִים עם התאמה לעברית. למעשה, פחות או יותר הכל עובד מהקופסה חוץ מכמה תיקונים קטנים שנדרשים.
        \item המנוע הוא \LuaLaTeX, על הכיווניות אחראית החבילה \E{Babel}, והעיצוב הוא של הערכה \E{Metropolis} האלגנטית, הברורה והנקיה.
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{על כתפי ענקים}
    ככל הידוע לי, היו לפחות שלושה פתרונות קודמים:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item של \href{https://web.archive.org/web/20111206041733/http://www.technion.ac.il/~ronen/latex/beamer_hebrew.html}{רונן אברבנאל}%
            \footnote{כתובת: \smallurl{https://web.archive.org/web/20111206041733/http://www.technion.ac.il/~ronen/latex/beamer_hebrew.html}}
        \item של \href{https://web.archive.org/web/20150327024158/http://technion.ac.il/~gai/beamer/index.html}{גיא שקד}%
            \footnote{כתובת: \smallurl{https://web.archive.org/web/20150327024158/http://technion.ac.il/~gai/beamer/index.html}}
        \item של \href{https://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2009-July/013721.html}{ופא ח׳ליקי}%
            \footnote{כתובת: \smallurl{https://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2009-July/013721.html}}
    \end{itemize}

    כמו שאפשר לראות, שני הראשונים כבר לא נמצאים יותר ברשת באופן עצמאי אלא רק בארכיון האינטרנט.
    הפתרון של רונן לא מתקמפל היטב בגרסאות חדשות;
    של גיא ושל ופא מבוססים על מחלקה לא סטנדרטית.
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{האקים א׳: קווים מפרידים}
    בגדול הכל עובד ישר מהקופסה. עם זאת, יש כמה דברים קטנים שצריך לשנות, כמו שאפשר לראות בקוד המקור של הקובץ הזה.

    שניים מהם קשורים לקווים המפרידים בשקופיות מיוחדות:

    \begin{itemize}
        \item תיקון של הקו המפריד בכותרת.
        \item תיקון של הקו המפריד בסעיפים והחלפת הכיוון שלו כך שיהיה הגיוני (התקדמות מימין לשמאל).
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{האקים ב׳: ענייני פונטים}
    ושניים קשורים לפונטים:

    \begin{itemize}
        \item משום מה מנגנון בחירת הפונטים של \E{Babel} לא עובד טוב, אז צריך לעקוף אותו ולהשתמש ב־\E{fontspec} ישירות.
        \item ניקוד מוצג נכון רק אם אין מלל לועזי לפניו בפסקה%
            \footnote{אני משער שהפונט העברי חוזר ללא המאפיין \E{\texttt{Script=Hebrew}}, ההכרחי לניקוד.}.
            כדי לעקוף את הבעיה אפשר לשים את המילה המנוקדת בסביבה מבודדת%
            \footnote{לדוגמה, בתוך \E{\texttt{\textbackslash mbox}} בתוך מתמטיקה; לא אלגנטי אבל עובד. אפשר, כמובן, ליצור פקודה יפה שעושה את זה.}.

            \begin{itemize}
                \item ככה זה נראה נכון: \E{abc} \nikud{נִקּוּד}\\
                \item וככה לא נכון: \E{abc} נִקּוּד
            \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{האקים ג׳: טבלאות}
    לא בדיוק האק, אלא משהו לשים לב אליו: סדר העמודות בטבלאות הוא משמאל לימין ולא מימין לשמאל.

    \vfill

    \begin{columns}[t]
        \column{0.50\textwidth}
        קלט:\\
        \begin{otherlanguage}{english}
            \bgroup\tt
            \textbackslash begin\{tabular\}\{r|r|r\}\\
            \quad\foreignlanguage{hebrew}{\fontspec{Pragmata Pro}{שמאל}} \&\\
            \quad\foreignlanguage{hebrew}{\fontspec{Pragmata Pro}{אמצע}} \&\\
            \quad\foreignlanguage{hebrew}{\fontspec{Pragmata Pro}{ימין}}\\
            \textbackslash end\{tabular\}
            \egroup
        \end{otherlanguage}

        \column{0.40\textwidth}
        פלט:\\
        \begin{tabular}{r|r|r}
            שמאל &
            אמצע &
            ימין
        \end{tabular}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{מה לא עובד?}
    הבעיה היחידה שנתקלתי בה ולא מצאתי פתרון עבורה היא בביבליוגרפיה עם \E{Bib\LaTeX}. רוב הרשומות ב־\E{\texttt{\textbackslash printbibliography}} מסתדרות מעולה, ושומרות על כיווניות בלי בעיה. לעומת זאת, רשומות של תרגומים שמשתמשות בשדה \E{\texttt{related}} ובשדה \E{\texttt{relatedtype}} עם הערך \E{\texttt{translationof}} מתחרבשות בחלק שמציג את הספר המקורי: כל האותיות מופיעות בסדר הפוך. אם מצאתם פתרון לבעיה, אשמח לשמוע מתחרבשים בחלק שמציג את המקור: כל האותיות מופיעות בסדר הפוך. אם מצאתם פתרון לבעיה, אשמח לשמוע :-) (פרטי יצירת קשר יש בעמוד השער).

    דוגמה לבעיה אפשר לראות בתרגום הוולשי של הארי פוטר במצגת הזאת:\\
    \smallurl{https://ac.digitalwords.net/\#nonacademic-2018-08-23}\\
    קובץ ה־\E{Bib\LaTeX} זמין כאן:
    \smallurl{https://gitlab.com/rwmpelstilzchen/bibliography.bib}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{מה צריך עוד לעשות?}
    כאמור, אני נתקלתי רק בבעיה אחת שלא הצלחתי לפתור. יכול להיות שאנשים עם צרכים אחרים משלי יתקלו בבעיות אחרות. אם נתקלת בבעיה כללית, אל תהסס/י לפנות אלי: אם מצאת פתרון, אשמח לשמוע אותו; אם לא מצאת פתרון, אשמח לנסות לעזור.
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{דוגמה למצגת מורכבת}
    הצורך ביצירת מצגת עברית עלה אצלי עבור הרצאה שהכנתי לכנס מיתופיה 2018 („הארי פוטר וכינויי הגוף השני”), הרצאה שהיא גלגול של הרצאה שהצגתי בכנסים אקדמיים (בלשניים וקלטולוגיים) לקהל הפוטריסטי. לא יכולתי להסתמך על מצגת באנגלית בגלל שלא כולם בקהל קוראים באנגלית באופן שוטף, כך שהייתי צריך לתרגם את המצגת הקיימת שהיתה לי לעברית. \E{PowerPoint} של מיקרוסופט או \E{Impress} של ליברה־אופיס הן לא אופציות: אני מעדיף למות תריסר מיתות משונות לפני שאגע בדברים האלה. מתוך הצורך הגיעה נבירה ב־\url{tex.stackexchange.com} ויצירת הפתרון הזה.

    למה אני מספר את זה? כי אם אתם רוצים לראות מצגת די מורכבת שעובדת יפה עם עברית ושקוד המקור שלה זמין, גשו אל:\\
    \smallurl{https://ac.digitalwords.net/\#nonacademic-2018-08-23}
\end{frame}



\part{ככה נראית שקופית של חלק}
\frame{\partpage}

\section{וככה סעיף לקראת הסוף}

\begin{frame}{הערת־אגב: פונטים למצגות}
    במצגת הזאת משמש הפונט \href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Sans}{\E{Open Sans}} של סטיב מטסון עם \href{https://yaronimus.wordpress.com/2014/01/19/\%D7\%90\%D7\%95\%D7\%A4\%D7\%9F-\%D7\%A1\%D7\%90\%D7\%A0\%D7\%A1-\%D7\%92\%D7\%95\%D7\%A4\%D7\%9F-\%D7\%A8\%D7\%A9\%D7\%AA-\%D7\%97\%D7\%99\%D7\%A0\%D7\%9E\%D7\%99-\%D7\%91\%D7\%A2\%D7\%99\%D7\%A6\%D7\%95\%D7\%91\%D7\%95-\%D7\%A9\%D7\%9C-\%D7\%99\%D7\%90/}{ההרחבה העברית} שעיצב ינק יונטף („הפונט של הארץ”).
    לדעתי זה פונט מעולה למצגות, בדומה ל־\E{Fira Sans} (הפונט הדיפולטיבי של \E{Metropolis}); $\mbox{אָלֶף}$ (\E{Alef}), עם כל חיבתי אליו, לא מתאים למצגות.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just an explanation for the second problem.

It seems that beamer only includes translations for a few languages. For theorems, etc., this seems to be limited to Brazilian, Croatian, English, French, German, Greek, Norsk, Polish, Serbian and Spanish. A note in beamerbasemisc.sty says this about handling of months:

> This is suboptimal; for full localization babel should be used.

I have actually used beamer in an unsupported language and I guess this is not uncommon. However, lots of cases won't demonstrate the issue as they won't require beamer-defined text as part of the content of the slides.

I suspect in this case, you'd need to contribute translations for Hebrew to get this working properly. You might be able to redefine the odd thing to get particular presentations working correctly for your own use, though, without doing a full translation. However, as ever with `beamer`, you probably have to trace what's happening through at least half a dozen files just to unpick the problem. `beamerbasetranslator.sty`, `translator.sty` etc.

The language mapping is present in `translator-language-mappings.tex`:

```
\DeclareOption{hebrew}         {\trans@use@and@alias{hebrew}    {Hebrew}}
```

`translator.sty` inputs this. However, what later happens is that `beamer` defaults to English when it cannot find a dictionary for Hebrew (because `beamer` doesn't have one). This is presumably a problem for the majority of languages defined since most of them lack `beamer`-specific translation dictionaries.

What you might try is to copy the relevant dictionary `translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict` to `translator-theorem-dictionary-Hebrew.dict` and then edit it, changing the names you actually need to use. Make the copy in the relevant directory of `TEXMFHOME` so that it does not get overwritten on updates. This will avoid errors due to something not being there which `beamer` expects since you won't delete any translations. But it will allow you to just add translations for terms you actually use. If you do more than this, you should consider submitting your dictionary or dictionaries upstream so that Hebrew will work out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thank you. But `babel` doesn't work in `XeLaTeX` (where `bidi` exists anyway). And I couldn't get `babel` and `beamer` to work nicely in `LaTeX` as it were...

Comment: @MathPhDStudent It isn't `babel`. `beamer` is using its own translation mechanism. (Actually I believe you can use `babel` in XeLaTeX but it is not really supported - one reason for me to stay with pdfLaTeX!) The point is that `beamer` will not use whatever multi-lingual support is available - be that `babel`, `polyglossia`, whatever - to translate strings. So you will have to provide at least a partial dictionary if you want it to translate those strings into Hebrew.

Comment: And, no, you won't get it to play nicely with `babel`. That is the point of the comment in the code. It is a comment *about* `beamer`. It is saying `beamer` *should* use `babel` (though it does not).

Comment: I guess there's only one solution left... I'll have to write a new LaTeX based document class with all the shindig to support reasonable presentations (even if no "animations" available).

Comment: @MathPhDStudent Surely it would be easier to provide a dictionary for `beamer`?! Obviously this would not address the other issue you identified but the second one seems far from insurmountable. Am I missing something? I've done similar things for another language for `biblatex` though I never attempted complete translation. But `beamer` uses quite small dictionaries so even providing a complete translation for a language should be quite doable.

Comment: No, it's not that. It's the fact that none of the examples online of Hebrew presentations actually work, and the one that does work does a terrible job. And I always found coming up with my own code to be easier than understanding the horrors of others. This shouldn't be too hard, I reckon. The `bidi` package does have a [non-working for me] class of this sort, and I can take ideas from there.

Comment: @MathPhDStudent I just checked. If you were to provide a complete translation, you would need to translate a total of 278 strings. However, many of these are minor variations e.g. `Theorem`, `Theorems`, `theorem` and `theorems`. Most are single words. A few consist of 2 or 3 words.

Comment: @MathPhDStudent Oh. OK. That's different. I just worried that maybe I had inadvertently suggested that the translation problem was a huge problem, and I wanted to be clear that that could be solved fairly easily. (Well, fairly easily if you know the target language - it isn't something I could do for Hebrew, as it were.)

Comment: Alright. It seems that I have some working minimal environment. Thanks for letting me know that there's little chance of working things out with the current tools.

Comment: @MathPhDStudent But I didn't say that! About the other problems, I have no idea. About this one, it would be quite straightforward since I'm assuming that you, unlike me, know Hebrew.

Comment: Oh, I know. I'm just confident enough in my search-fu to think that there's probably no good answer for that. In any case, What I have now works pretty awesomely. With `babel` and with everything else.

Comment: Yeah, so I ended up writing a pretty nifty code last night. During the semester I'll tweak it, and over the summer I'll turn it into a proper document class and spread it out for beta testing. It's fairly cool that I did that. So thanks again!